# how to create multiple charts with vba

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts

I need some help.... I have this code in sheet1:

```
Sheets("kips").Select

Dim i As Integer 'rows
Dim j As Integer 'columns

i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To 5
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .Parent.Name = "Chart_" & (j - 1)
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        '.Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        'Cells(1, j).Address
        .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Address
        .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
        
        End With
        
    End With
Next j
```

And I need to add new charts in an other sheet, so I tried to use the same code:

```
Sheets("sheet2").Select

Dim i As Integer 'rows
Dim j As Integer 'columns

i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To 5
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .Parent.Name = "Chart_" & (j - 1)
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        '.Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        'Cells(1, j).Address
        .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Address
        .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
        
        End With
        
    End With
Next j
```

Is the same model of the tabel, but I need to put this in another sheet, here is my tabel:

[image: data]

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Be careful with using `.Select` for a worksheet and then using `Activesheet`. Selecting a sheet does not necessarily make it active. Use `Activate` instead. As an alternative, you shouldn't select or activate a worksheet at all. Create a variable object for the worksheet and assign it: `Dim ws As Worksheet; Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("kips")`. Then use the reference to `ws` and you guarantee which sheet you're referencing, which is always safer.

Comment: but how I reference a ws? Because I need to do 4 graphs with this table, so, how I can make a code who can choice separat this ws in 4 graphs?

Answer (score 2):

When working with sheets it's always a good idea to create sheet variables, assign them to the sheets you're working with, and then use those variables instead of referring to sheets via their name, or "Select sheet >> ActiveSheet" etc

```vb
Dim i As Long 'use Long
Dim j As Long
Dim wsCht As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ActiveSheet
Set wsCht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

i = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To 5
    With wsCht.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .Parent.Name = "Chart_" & (j - 1)
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            '.Name = "=" & wsData.Name & "!" & wsdata.Cells(1, j).Address
            .XValues = "='" & wsData.Name & "'!" & _
                   wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, 1), wsData.Cells(i, 1)).Address
            .Values = "='" & wsData.Name & "'!" & _
                   wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, j), wsData.Cells(i, j)).Address
        
        End With
        
    End With
Next j
```